# How to send non-model data using a submit button (Razorpages)

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I need to post a form but I also need to include the Id of the widget I want to remove from the model collection. Can I pass extra data with a submit, that is not part of the model?

I have generated html using a foreach loop. This displays the ID of a widget. The model for this page is a collection of widgets.

So the code used to display all widget Id's is as follows:

```
    @foreach (var widget in widgets){
        @i++; // Assume declared above or could use simple for loop ... 
        Widget @widget.Id 
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Widgets[i].Id" /> // For binding the collection on POST
        <br />
    }
```

This displays:

- Widget 1
- Widget 2
- Widget 3
- ...etc

I would like the user to have the option to remove Widget 2 from the list.

So the display will be something like this:

- Widget 1 [x]
- Widget 2 [x]
- Widget 3 [x]
- ...etc

I would like to post the model back to the server and pass the Id of the widget... how do I do this?

If I use an input like below, how can I add the Id to it?

```
    @foreach (var widget in widgets){
        @i++; // Assume declared above or could use simple for loop ... 
        Widget @widget.Id 
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Widgets[i].Id" />  // For binding the collection on POST
        <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="RemoveWidget" name="x" />
        <br />
    }
```

I've thought about creating a global hidden input field and setting this field to the Id using javascript before the submit is sent, but I assume there is a better way than this?

Comment: Would the actionlink create a POST? I thought this would only create a GET.  The only place this model exists at this point is on the webpage (not persisted in the back end), so I need to post the form back (with my widget Id's in it) so they can be binded (bound?) server side, then remove from the collection and re-display...

Comment: No, the ActionLink would not create a POST. ActionLink renders an anchor tag <a> in which you can route your actions with a parameter. If you want to perform a POST, then you would need to use AJAX. I will show that method also in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your desired functionality, I am using ActionLink with a parameter:

```
@foreach (var widget in widgets){
    Widget @widget.Id @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Home", new { id = @widget.Id})<br />
}
```

And in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id) 
{
//Get your widget ID here and do the deletion as required.
return View("Your View");
}
```

You can style your ActionLink as required like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Home", new { id = @widget.Id},new { @style="your style goes here" });
```

**EDIT**:

You can use AJAX if you want to POST your data to your controller. Specifically in your case, I will show you an example:

```
@foreach (var widget in widgets){
    Widget @widget.Id : <a href="#" data-id="@widget.Id" onclick="confirmDelete(this)"></a><br />
}
```

In you AJAX:

```
function confirmDelete(event) {
        var recordToDelete = $(event).attr("data-id"); //Get your current widget id here

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this widget") == true) {
        //Prepare our data
        var json = {
            id: recordToDelete
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json) },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data == "success") {
                    alert("Successfully deleted selected widget");
                    location.reload();
                }                        
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Could not delete selected widget. Please try again!");
            },
        });
    }
};
```

And finally in your Controller:

```
//Delete a widget based on the ID that you get from your View
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {               
        dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
        string id = jsondata["id"];
        if(id != "")
        {             
            int getid = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            //Call your db or your logic to delete the file
            DatabaseAccess data = new DatabaseAccess();
            string result = data.DeleteFile(getid);

            if(result.Equals("Success"))
            {
                return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("fail", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }                     
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("notfound", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
       return Json("dberror", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I don't think this would work for me.  There is an assumption that this is being persisted on the server somewhere, but this is not the case. In your example there is a trip to the server (the Ajax call), then another trip reloading the page... So I would simply get a brand new page...

The model exists on the page only and is the only copy. I will update the question to try and show this...

In my post I need to send the inputs (part of the model so properties are bound) and the selected value (via some the way).

Comment: @Craig You can build your own model in the AJAX option and then POST it with your widget Id also. It all depends on how you generate your model in your AJAX like I showed you in my answer. And there is only one trip to the server where you would delete your widget plus do additional stuff with your model and then based on the result which is in JSON , you can do whatever action you want on your Razor page and you would not get a brand new page but only the alert that you show based on your result from the server. I hope I am making sense here.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but I need to show only Widget 1 and Widget 3 after the user has pressed the delete button. If I have to manually construct the model into json, by traversing the DOM, I would favour the hidden input Id method in the last paragraph of my question.  If I am constructing the model to post in an AJAX request, I may as well simply post the form and take advantage of the model binding as it is the only thing on the page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Craig I am not quite sure I follow your question then. In your problem statement, you are getting your widget id's from your collection and you want that each individual widget should have an action based on that id? From the looks of it your model already has a field called `Id`. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: My model has a collection of widgets and each widget has a property Id.

Comment: The model does not have an Id property itself.

Comment: I was going to use some javascript code to update a hidden field before the submit, this would show the Id of the delete button just pressed. I could then use this input in the controller (passed via parameters).  This seems like a long winded way of passing an Id when submitting a form and wondered if there was a more elegant way of doing things (maybe in some helper class etc).

Comment: @Craig You can create your own logic to create a unique `id` based on a for loop like you mentioned in your question and then send these values using my first method but the catch is that once the call is complete  and the page is refreshed, then new `id` will be assigned to each widget. Until you persist something to the server, you will not be able to get the assigned `id` of a widget. I would suggest that you create a new field in your model called `widgetID` and then assign values to it after your first call to the server.